# How to add class in tbody and td of yii2 grid view?

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

Using yii2 grid view I can add extra classes into table. but how to add in tbody and into td?

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered my-table">
   <thead>...</thead>
   <tbody class="tbl-body">
      <tr>
         <td class="emp-name">Emp 1</td>
         <td class="emp-age">25</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
```

---

```
 GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'filterPosition' => GridView::FILTER_POS_HEADER,
    'tableOptions' => ['class' => 'table table-striped table-bordered my-table'],
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
```

This is what i have used to add extra class i.e my-table in table but how to add tbl-body,emp-name,emp-age?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like that:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'attribute_name',
    'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'td-class'],
    'headerOptions' => ['class' => 'th-class']
],
```

Reference to the docs: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/output-data-widgets#column-classes

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it not possible to add any option in GridView to the body tag, but you could use it as a child of the table in your CSS file:

```
table.my-table tbody {
    ...
}
```

The options for the td tag as described in the anwser of @vvpanchev above.

Comment: I found the solution to add class in table body tag. it's by using jquery